# How to independtly control colors of individual elements in multi-element chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

In short, I'm constructing a multi-element chart, containing violin, point, and line elements, hoping to represent individual distributions and interactions. I'm adding a hypothetical example.

However, I'm unable to figure out how to control the fill of the violin plots without affecting other elements. For example, I want the fill of the violin plots as NA (or white), while I want to fill in geom_point. In my case, manual fill affects all of the chart elements. It's probably an easy solution, but I cannot figure it out at the moment.

```
summ <- ddply(SOJA, .(SORTA, MVR), summarise, CANOPY = mean(CANOPY))

a1 <- ggplot(SOJA, aes(as.factor(MVR), CANOPY, fill=SORTA)) +
geom_violin()+
geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(), size = 2, shape=21, stroke = 1) +
  geom_point(data = summ, aes(group=SORTA), colour="black", 
             position = position_dodge(width=0.75), size=4, shape=21, stroke = 2) +
  geom_line(data = summ, aes(group=SORTA), colour="black",
            position = position_dodge(width=0.75), size=0.8) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("25 cm", "50 cm")) +
  theme_classic () +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25, colour = "black"),
axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12))+ 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())

a1 <- a1 + theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_text(family="Palatino Linotype", colour="black", size=14), legend.text = element_text(family="Palatino Linotype", colour="black", size=14)) + labs(fill = "Cultivar:")
a1 <- a1 + theme(axis.line=element_line(size=1))
a1 <- a1 + labs(title="a) Interactions of cultivars and row spacings", subtitle ="p = 0.001") + theme(plot.title = element_text(colour="black", size=14, face="bold")) + theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(colour="black", size=10))
a1 <- a1 + labs(x = "Row spacing", y= "Days to canopy closure")
```

[image]

Now the second question is a bit more exploratory and for the debate. I wonder if I could avoid making separate charts for the main effects and interactions. Let's say, that I want to show the distribution plus mean crossbar of CANOPY observations only for the main effect of ROW SPACING, and add to that means and interaction lines of ROW SPACING and CULTIVAR. Here I don't know how to fill mean points of interaction to be the same as for individual observations. Furthermore, is there a possibility to also arrange jitter points according to each cultivar at the specific row spacing (as in the example above)?

```
> a1 <- ggplot(SOJA, aes(as.factor(MVR), CANOPY)) + geom_violin()+
> stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "crossbar", width = 0.5,colour =
> "black")+ geom_jitter(aes(fill=SORTA),size = 3, shape=21, stroke = 1,
> width=0.15, alpha = 0.75) +   geom_point(data = summ,
> aes(group=SORTA), colour="black", 
>              position = position_dodge(width=0.75), size=5, shape=21, stroke = 2) +   geom_line(data = summ, aes(group=SORTA),
> colour="black",
>             position = position_dodge(width=0.75), size=0.8) + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("25 cm", "50 cm")) +   theme_classic () + 
> theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0,
> colour = "black"),
>         axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25, colour = "black"), axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12))+    theme(strip.background = element_blank())
> 
> a1 <- a1 + theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title =
> element_text(family="Palatino Linotype", colour="black", size=14),
> legend.text = element_text(family="Palatino Linotype", colour="black",
> size=14)) + labs(fill = "Cultivar:") a1 <- a1 +
> theme(axis.line=element_line(size=1)) a1 <- a1 + labs(title="a) Main
> effect of row spacings and interaction with cultivar", subtitle ="p =
> 0.001 (row spacing) \np = 0.001 (interaction)") + theme(plot.title = element_text(colour="black", size=14, face="bold")) +
> theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(colour="black", size=10)) a1 <- a1
> + labs(x = "", y= "Days to canopy closure")
```

[image]

Comment: Change `geom_violin() +` to `geom_violin(fill = NA) +`. When you put an `aes` inside the initial call to ggplot, all subsequent layers inherit this aesthetic mapping by default. This can be changed on a per-layer basis.